# Python 3: unpack two float numbers in byte format

Tags: python-3.x

```
data =  b'0.01,71.5\r\n'  #from PySerial to RaspPi USB
a,b = [float(x) for x in data]
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the data object into list to iterate over it. You can take following approach:

```
In [20]: data =  b'0.01,71.5\r\n'  #from PySerial to RaspPi USB 
    ...: a,b = [float(x) for x in data.decode('utf-8') 
    ...: .split(',')]                                                                                                                                                             

In [21]: a,b                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[21]: (0.01, 71.5)
```

Comment: please consider accepting the answer or upvote if it works for you.

Comment: The solution works for awhile but eventually get error message: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: That because somewhere in your code instead of byte, data is coming as tuple. you need to debug and find if its data issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding again. The data received prints as b'0.01,71.5\r\n'. I didn't think this was a tuple but it must be? This comes directly from data=ser.readline(), print (data), in Python3